# mysql fetch array individual echo php

Tags: php, variables, echo

need to get row content from a mysql select statement. Currently starting at high id and desc. Need to take the highest id and get it, and the next 15 in line, and need to store them as variables. Here is an example:

```
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "_p";
 $password = "1";
 $dbname = "w";
 mysql_connect("localhost", "p", "s") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("p") or die(mysql_error()); 

 $highest_id = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM NE2"), 0);
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT content, id FROM NE2 order by ID desc LIMIT 15  ");
 while($row[0] = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

      echo $row[0]['content'];
```

Comment: would appreciate an answer

Comment: You have LIMIT 10 how would you get 15?

Comment: see adjustment abra. thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @AbraCadaver please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with one query and access the top 16 ids, (the max id and the 15 next ids)

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "_p";
$password = "1s";
$dbname = "wc";

mysql_connect($servername, $username, $dbname) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("we_ppp") or die(mysql_error());

// Let's get the 16 first highest id's and their content
// Why 16 ? We want the highest and the 15 next
$result = mysql_query("SELECT content, id FROM SEARCH2 order by ID desc LIMIT 0, 16");

// Now it's easied to handle if we just stack the result in a big array
$data_array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $data_array[] = $row;
}

// Now we have $data_array[0] to $data_array[15] (the 16th row) each one containing
// an associative array resulting from the mysql_fetch_assoc().
// Now if I want the highest id :

$highest_id = $data_array[0]['id'];
$highest_content = $data_array[0]['content'];

// And the next 15 are
for($i = 1; $i < 16; $i++) { // We start at the second line until the 16th (numer 15)
        echo $highest[$i]['id'];
        echo $highest[$i]['content'];
}

// Now you do whatever you want with $highest and the next ones
```

The code will be more readable here :

http://pastebin.com/jGF94WJ2

Comment: how would I reference $highest[$i]['content']; as the $string in ImageString($im, 5, 30, 25, $string, $black);}} and then if i want to do it again with $string2, which was the next $highest[$i]['content'];

Answer (score 0):

use it like this

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT content, id FROM S_ENGINE2 order by ID desc LIMIT 15");
 if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
 {
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
         echo $row['content']."<br>"; 
     }
 }
```

may this will help you

Comment: please see the update. the second instance is not working

Answer (score 0):

The while loop executes row by row, and at an instance you could have only one row (just like array index), so do like

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
       echo $row["id"];
       echo $row["contetnt"]);
    }
```

> `NOTE:` `mysql_*` is deprecated and is not advised . Use PDO for secure database interations

Comment: please see the update. the second instance is not working

Comment: @PlacePrintApp Please change it to `$row = ` not `$row[0]` or `$row[1]` and access it like `$row["id"]` not `$row[0]["id"]`

Comment: then how do i get the second occurrence of row, or the first occurrence of row as a variable of its own?

Comment: for example what if i want to get the first result and store it in $variable and get the second result and store it in $variable2

Comment: @PlacePrintApp You can use a separate array for that, while loop iterates row by row, for start your row index will be 0 for next 1 and so on...if need to store some values you can use separate array for that